# How to control high output voltage boost converter

Tags: voltage, boost

Input 24 V, output > 100 V.

I have looked at switching controller ICs on Mouser.com but for my input voltage they are designed only to output 50 V. [Like this TI TL5001](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/TL5001AIP?qs=NLW4NjXEBS7rMvLxEkq2ag%3D%3D)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a boost controller like [this one](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3757), which controls an **external MOSFET**, then the FET determines max output voltage.

The controller doesn't see the output voltage on any of its pins. It only sees the feedback voltage, which is attenuated by the feedback voltage divider.

TL5001 doesn't have a proper FET driver, so it may not be a good choice.

Also note that boost doesnt work very well when the output/input ratio is too high, as inductor current can become very high. Depending on your application and required output current, a transformer based converter may be a better option. You can always ask "what is the best converter topology for my application" but you will have to give all the info.

Comment: Thanks. In case I needed to add a second boost stage, how may I go about dealing with this larger input voltage (output of the first stage). Do I power the chip with the regular Vin, and open the connection on the top end of the inductor and connect that lead of the inductor to the Vout of the first stage?

Comment: 2 boost stages? why not use a transformer?

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of flyback controllers that can provide 100 volts or more such as this one that produces 200 volts: -

[image]

So, you can either pay for simplicity or work hard to get a cheaper design.

Comment: How did you come across this controller? I had looked at the Linear Technology website previously, able to tell me why the "Flyback, Forward and Isolated Controllers" and "External Power Switch Boost" sections do not have a Vout filter?

Comment: No they don’t and that’s because of the variations and range that a transformer brings to the party. Old fashioned method of selecting only those items that are dedicated as flyback controllers and looking at the input voltage range and sot23 package! @A.S.